# Removing a module when I add a new better one?

Tags: wireless, drivers, realtek

I'm using this guide to install my TL-WN822N (Wireless/Wifi).

I need to add `8192cu` at the end of `/etc/modules`, but I see another module there (Copy-Paste file):

```
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.
# Parameters can be specified after the module name.

lp
8192cuvhba
vhba
```

Should I remove it or is that unnecessary? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

That's not another module. That's probably been added (mistakenly) by you. Note that the "module"'s name is `8192cuvhba` which is just the name of the module you actually want (`8192cu`) plus the name of the module on the next line ([`vhba`](http://cdemu.sourceforge.net/about/vhba/)).

It looks like you just did a blind copy/paste at some point and added that line. Delete it and everything should be fine. Your file should end up like this:

```
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.
# Parameters can be specified after the module name.

lp
8192cu
vhba
```